# How to return html instead of strings in php dom parser

Tags: php, html, dom

```
<?php
    $convert = function($src) {
    return '<div>'.$src.'</div>';
};

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml(getHTML());
foo($doc, $convert);
echo "after: ", $doc->savehtml(), "\n\n";


function foo(DOMDocument $doc, $fn) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $imgs = array();
    foreach( $xpath->query('/html/body//img') as $n ) {
        $imgs[] = $n;
    }

    foreach($imgs as $n) {
        $txt = $fn($n->getAttribute('src'));
        $div = $doc->createElement('div', $txt);
        $n->parentNode->replaceChild($div, $n);
    }
}

function getHTML() {
return '<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
    <p>lorem ipsum <img src="a.jpg" alt="img#1"/></p>
    <p>dolor sit amet<img src="b.jpg" alt="img#2"/></p>
    <div><div><div><img src="c.jpg" alt="img#3" /></div></div></div>
</body></html>';
}
```

In the above code in the third line  doesn't appear as html in the output, it show as the string. How to return a html tag in this program.

Comment: if it is not possible to add html tags in the 3 rd line, how to create it using createElement() function.

Comment: Another "here is my code, try to figure out the problem and debug it for me" question. Please provide a trimmed down piece of code, and "before" and "after" strings.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not asking for debugging. This code works fine. My question is this code returns only string as out put, not html. why?

Comment: using echo instead of return doesn't work here

Comment: What's the difference between a string and HTML? HTML can be in a string, it's absolutely not clear what you mean.

Comment: if I put `<div>` inside the return value, it displays as `&lt;div&gt;`

Comment: Is there any other way to show html notations in this code,

Comment: I managed to read my way through your code (you really shouldn't do things using this `$convert = function(...)`, it decreases readability enourmously, what is wrong with `$txt = convert($n->getAttribute('src'))`?) and the problem seems to lie within the `$doc->createElement()` part. You pass a string like '<div>...' in there, and the createElement will encode the html tags (`<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`). You simply shouldn't call your function but instead just pass the text you want in the div tag, and you'll be fine.

Comment: passing text works fine, but I couldn't pass <div> kind of things. and without createElement() I can't replace <img> with <div> tag

Answer (score 0):

Use echo() not return() when printing the HTML

Comment: Sorry my friend, this is why I posted the full code. echo does not works for this context

Comment: Sorry you are right, what I meant was that you should echo the function like <?php echo getHMTL() ?>

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml(getHTML());
replaceImageTags($doc);
echo "after: ", $doc->savehtml(), "\n\n";

function replaceImageTags(DOMDocument $doc) 
{

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $imgs = array();
    foreach($xpath->query('/html/body//img') as $n ) {
        $imgs[] = $n;
    }

    foreach($imgs as $n) 
    {
        $div = $doc->createElement('div', $n->getAttribute('src'));
        $n->parentNode->replaceChild($div, $n);
    }
}

function getHTML() {
return '<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
    <p>lorem ipsum <img src="a.jpg" alt="img#1"/></p>
    <p>dolor sit amet<img src="b.jpg" alt="img#2"/></p>
    <div><div><div><img src="c.jpg" alt="img#3" /></div></div></div>
</body></html>';
}
```

Outputs:

```
after: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> <html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
    <p>lorem ipsum <div>a.jpg</div></p>
    <p>dolor sit amet<div>b.jpg</div></p>
    <div><div><div><div>c.jpg</div></div></div></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: it is fine, but instead of a.jpg in the out put can you bring some html elements like <b>a.jpg</b>.